# Python simple code arrangement

Tags: python

The following code:

```
list1=['hello','bye']
list2=['john','dave','joe','bob']

for say in range (2):
    print list1[say]
    for name in range (4):
        print list2[name]
```

The result is:

```
hello 
bye   
john  
dave  
joe   
bob
```

How to arrange the code so the result will be like this:

```
hello
john
dave
joe
bob
bye
john
dave
joe
bob
```

I'm new to coding. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code seems correct but it can be written much more neatly (which is immaterial)

Comment: The range object used to control the loops doesn't replenish.  Therefore, the second loop (range(4)) is exhausted when it comes around again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1=['hello','bye']
list2=['john','dave','joe','bob']

for listitem1 in list1:
    print(listitem1)
    for x in list2:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Now i realized that i'm lacking knowledge of xrange.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the lists, its easier:

```
list1=['hello','bye']
list2=['john','dave','joe','bob']
for say in list1:
    print(say)
    for name in list2:
        print(name)
```